# docker run command ends up in : nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "events" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Tags: nginx, docker, configure, events

I have installed nginx-extras from Ubuntu bash shell in my desktop Windows 10 O.S. The is required to spin up a docker container for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor web assembly application for serving the static web pages. 
My nginx.conf:

```
events { }
   http {
      include mime.types;
      types {
         application/wasm wasm;
       }
     server {
        listen 80;
        index index.html;
        location / {
           root /var/www/web;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
     }
}
```

My build command was successful.

However when I wanted to create a container using the command:
docker run -p 8080:80 docker-wasm-blazor
It gave me an error:

[emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "﻿events" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "﻿events" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

I am very new to nginx so any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've very likely, as you have the same problem I ran into, that you've copy and pasted that NGINX conf into Visual Studio.

Open it in Notepad++ change the encoding to UTF-8 (not BOM) and it should work just fine.

Comment: Schooled by StackOverflow once again. Amazing! Thanks.